# SQL - Calculate YTD number

Tags: sql, postgresql

Here is the table:

| Name | Month | Num |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Metric | 1/1/22 | 10 |
| Metric | 1/2/22 | 10 |
| Metric | 1/3/22 | 10 |
| Metric | 1/4/22 | 10 |
| Metric | 1/5/22 | 10 |
| Metric | 1/6/22 | 10 |
| Metric | 1/7/22 | 10 |
| Metric | 1/8/22 | 10 |
| Metric | 1/9/22 | 10 |
| Metric | 1/10/22 | 10 |
| Metric | 1/11/22 | 10 |
| Metric | 1/12/22 | 10 |
| Metric | YTD |  |

How to calculate the YTD number which sums the numbers in the Num column based on the month of the year? For example, it should return 40 right now. In May, it should return 50.

Thanks!

Comment: `date_part('doy', dt)`

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551), which also applies to table definitions and sample data.